# Javascript XML Parser wrapper

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I created an XML wrapper to easily access XML data.
Please tell me what do you think about it.

- Performance
- Scalability
- Anything else...

This is how you use it:

```
var xml = new Xml(dataString);
xml.load("UserEmail");
alert(xml.length + ", " + xml.getValueAt(0)); // Out: 2, jchen@contoso.com
```

XML source file:

```
<Users>
    <Users>
        <UserEmail>jchen@contoso.com</UserEmail>
        <UserPassword>
            BA56E5E0366D003E98EA1C7F04ABF8FCB3753889
        </UserPassword>
    </Users>
    <Users>
        <UserEmail>Kim@contoso.com</UserEmail>
        <UserPassword>
            07B7F3EE06F278DB966BE960E7CBBD103DF30CA6
        </UserPassword>
    </Users>
</Users>
```

Source:

```
function Xml(xmlString) {
    var parser = function() {
        if (typeof window.DOMParser != "undefined") {
            return (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlString,
                    "text/xml");
        }
        else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined"
                && new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
            var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = "false";
            xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlString);
            return xmlDoc;
        }
        else {
            throw new Error("XML parser not found");
        }
    };

    var data = parser(xmlString);
    var elements = null;
    this.length = 0;

    this.load = function(nodeName){
        elements = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName(nodeName);
        this.length = elements.length;
    };

    this.getValueAt = function(index) {
        if(!elements || index >= this.length){
            return null;
        }
        var element = elements.item(index);

        return element.childNodes[0].data;
    };
}
```

Comment: It can usefully handle very simple XMLs. It doesn't retrieve the value of attributes. It gives worthless values for element nodes. It doesn't support a decent selector engine. If it's good for your purposes, use it.

Comment: "Would you write your own XML Parser? Only if you're f***ing crazy." http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp

Comment: @David pmpl nice one ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick read :

- `Xml` seems like a bad name for your wrapper, you should consider something like `xmlParser` ?
- I would allow access to `data` and `elements` by using `this` instead of `var` because you wrap so little of the XML parser API
- `this.length` seems wrong ( the parser has no length), maybe `loadedElementCount`, but even that is pretty bad, I would just let the caller use `elements.length`.
- I would `return elements` in `this.load`, since that is pretty much what the caller would need next.
- You are not checking for falsey values of `nodeName` in `this.load`
- I would not create a `var element` in getValueAt, I would just return `elements.item(index).childNodes[0].data`